# Override specific properties of a style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm creating a new style for the TabControl including a new ItemContainerStyle for the items. The new style works fine, except that I need the possibility to add features to the ItemContainerStyle when using the style. In detail this is the Header property

```
  <TabControl x:Name="myTabControl" SelectionChanged="myTabControl_SelectionChanged">
            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Title}"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TabControl>
```

which works OK. But it overrides the style completely. the BasedOn property would help, but I don't have access to the key of the ItemContainerStyle since it is embedded in the TabControls' style. How can I simply update a property of the style without overriding the style completely?

Thanks

Comment: Do you create your tab Items dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bit of a difference in the way styles in WPF compared to css. In Wpf they work completely off of inheritance, [this is the basic document on how styles work](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon(v=vs.95).aspx). So if a key is not provided for you I think you are out of luck when using the BasedOn inheritance.

However, Microsoft does provide a useful utility in Visual Studio Blend. In the Objects and Timelines Window you right click then select an "edit a style", This will do all the heavy lifting for you. If you are going to be doing a lot of small changes on the style I would suggest you make a copy, and give it a Key, then use the BasedOn property to make your small changes that you want.

I Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I was hoping that I could get rid of doing this. This is what I did in the past. But costs a lot of extra code. Since I want to have a global style for all TabControl, I now have to still put some extra style in my ItemContainers just to get the text in.

Answer (score 0):

You can base your style on the implicitly applied default style:

```
<Style TargetType="TabItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}">
```

Comment: Hi Fratyx. I tried this one, but since the type TabItem is not overridden but the TabItem inside the "main" style for the TabControl it doesn't work.